# When querying Graph API via Service Fabric I do not get all extended properties

Tags: azure-service-fabric, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

I have created a small console app to try and get the optionalClaims from the Application manifest via Graph API.

This works as expected when querying through the console app but when i attempt to do this in my Service Fabric instance running locally I get alot less extendedProperties with my API call.

Here is the code

```
  var groups = new List<Group>();
        var userQuery = _addClient.DirectoryObjects.OfType<Application>().Where(application => application.AppId.Equals(objectId));
        var batchResult = await _addClient.Context.ExecuteBatchAsync(userQuery);
        var app = batchResult[0].SuccessResult.CurrentPage[0] as Application;
        var optionalClaims = app.GetExtendedProperties()[OptionalClaims] as Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataComplexValue;
        var idToken = optionalClaims.Properties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == IDToken) as Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataProperty;
        var items = (idToken.Value as Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataCollectionValue).Items;
```

When i run that code through a console app I get all the extended properties but when i run it through ServiceFabric i only get a few of them (and not the one I want)

Both using

Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient 2.1.1
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 3.19.6

although i can see the console app request and data coming back but am trying to get service fabric to go via fiddler so i can see if it is messing with the request to Graph

Any help would be great

Comment: How are you authenticating to AD? if you are using the current process user, it will get your windows credentials when running locally, when it runs on SF it run will uses the same user as the Fabric.exe service, and it will not have the same permissions as your local user.

Comment: Im using client credentials to access graph API